# appcompat-v7:26 EditText always white

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-appcompat

I'm new to android programming, but all the issues that describe my issue don't seem to help.

[Edittext color is white in appcompat 22.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114541/edittext-color-is-white-in-appcompat-22-2)

[Android EditText Text Color is always white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678512/android-edittext-text-color-is-always-white)

[Android edittext color white on white background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003857/android-edittext-color-white-on-white-background)

Surely its something super silly I'm looking over

[image: IssuePictured]

My Activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
            android:hint="@string/user_name"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

My Styles XML

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#0000FF</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#0000FF</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#0000FF</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Graddle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: change theme in style.xml and check

Comment: I changed it to Theme.AppCompat and it was the same results Is there another you suggest?

Comment: can you post your app gradle also ??

Comment: @merjr Kindly check my answer

Comment: @OmarDanisha added

Comment: What's the theme you set in your manifest?

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here posted by @Dahnark:

[How to customize EditText field in android using AppCompat v7:21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081900/how-to-customize-edittext-field-in-android-using-appcompat-v721)

Try to add the next code inside your `EditText`

```
 style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
```

Check in real device.

In my `EditText` works, this is my EditText:

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editTextFacebookID"
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:hint="Facebook ID"
     android:textColor="@color/md_text"                
     android:textColorHint="@color/md_disabled_hint_text" />
```

You can check *md_text* and *md_disabled_hint_text colors* here:
 [Google Colors](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette)

And this is a v19 style of my app:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_red_500</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/md_red_700</item>
     <item name="colorAccent">@color/md_blue_A200</item>
     <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/md_black_1000_25</item>
     <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/md_black_1000_50</item>
     <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/md_grey_200</item>
     <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/md_black_1000_75</item>
     <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">@bool/translucentNavigationBar</item>
     <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">@bool/translucentStatusBar</item>

     <!-- Navigation Drawer Arrow Style. -->
     <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

     <!-- Overflow Button Style. -->
     <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowStyle</item>
 </style>
```

My EditText is gray when is unfocused, and blue focused, it takes the
 color from colorAccent.

It changes color when I change the AppTheme.

Answer (score 0):

Change the appcomcat version as below and check

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'`

Comment: I added my graddle file to the issue. I do have the compile in the file already.

Answer (score 0):

You should add **`android:theme`** in **[TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html)** instead of ***EditText*** Section .

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

You should set

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
```

Comment: I added the theme and the text still appears to be white

Comment: @merjr You should use `v7:26.0.1` version

Comment: That causes my project to throw a Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1

Comment: @merjr https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397066/error39-13-failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0

Comment: That fixed the compile! Thanks. Sadly the text is still while when I'm typing from the keyboard. Hint text is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to try this:-

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Your Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And Update youe **style.xml** like this:-

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Text is still appearing white when i type